# Trying to add mongo indexes using generics

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregate

We normally add indexes using Builders like this

```
var keys = Builders<DocumentFolder>.IndexKeys.Ascending("Property1").Descending("Property2");
var opts = new CreateIndexOptions();
opts.Unique = false;
Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(keys, opts);
```

I'm trying to make this more generic for a dynamic collection we are adding, so I tried this

```
var Indexes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"Property1", "A"},
    {"Property2", "D"}
};
var keys = Indexes.Aggregate(Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys, 
    (current, next) => next.Value == "A" ? 
    current.Ascending(next.Key) : current.Descending(next.Key));
Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(keys, new CreateIndexOptions {Unique = isUnique});
```

But I am getting a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.IndexKeysDefinition' to 'MongoDB.Driver.IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder'" error.  From what I understand of Aggregate, both code segments should be returning equivalent objects.  Am I mistaken or do I have something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to get Aggregate to work and just couldn't get it working.  I assume it has something to do with Ascending/Descending returning a different Type than IndexKeys.  This works though.

```
IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument> builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys;
List<IndexKeysDefinition<BsonDocument>> definitions = 
    Indexes.Select(index => index.Value == "A" ? 
    builder.Ascending(index.Key) : 
    builder.Descending(index.Key)).ToList();
IndexKeysDefinition<BsonDocument> keys = 
    Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys.Combine(definitions);
Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(keys, new CreateIndexOptions {Unique = isUnique});
```

I'll leave this open for a while, if someone can make aggregate work I'll accept their answer since that was the original question.